# Subtract remaining hour from a day using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will identify a Sunday and highlight values in Col M if they are greater than 1 and has the text "waiting" in col P.

What I want to do is:

1. I have the date and time format in MM/D/YYYY TIME (example) - 1/22/2017 23:30
2. I want to subtract the Sunday time of the date with a cut of time of 23:59 and that remaining number should be subtracted with the value in col M and if still the value is greater than col M then it should be highlighted in Red.

**Sample Scenario:**

If the date/time is 1/22/2017 21:00 in col K, then the remaining hour here is 0.3 hours..this should be subtracted from the value in col M, lets say col M has 1.3, so 1.3-0.3 = 1. So it should be highlighted.

**Sample Output:**
[image: Sample Output]

**Code:**

```
Sub SundayDatefilter()

Dim r, lastrow, remainingDay As Long

lastrow = Range("M:P").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 2 To lastrow
      remainingDay = 0

        If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
                remainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

             If InStr(1, Range("P" & r).Text, "waiting", vbTextCompare) > 0     Then

                 If Range("M" & r) - remainingDay >= 1 Then
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                 Else
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                 End If
             End If
        End If
    Next r
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Care to show a screenshot of a sample sheet with input data and another screenshot with how the output will look like?

Comment: [link](https://s23.postimg.org/5cw1q5ujf/stack.jpg) - here is the link. Col K has the date and time, Col M has the value. Here time is Sunday 9PM, to the remaining hour is 0.3. So 1.5-0.3 is 1.2, which is still greater than 1 so this should not be colored. If it is less than 1 then it should be colored. But the values should remain the same and the subtraction should not be seen in the excel.

Comment: I am tracing the code now and I'm getting 0.125, not 0.3. Also, you should use `Double` as the data type of `remainingDay` as `Long` ignores the decimal part because it's an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, just change the data type of remainingDay as `Long` is an integer type (no decimal part).

```
Sub SundayDatefilter()
   Dim r, lastrow, remainingDay As Double   '<--- Correction

   lastrow = Range("M:P").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 2 To lastrow
      remainingDay = 0

      If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
         remainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

         If InStr(1, Range("P" & r).Text, "waiting", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If Range("M" & r) - remainingDay < 1 Then   '<--- Correction
               Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
               Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next r

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't give the desired result. Even after the subtraction, if the value in M is greater than 1, it is being colored. So basically, even after the subtraction, if the value is > 1, the it should not be colored.

Comment: Then you just have to flip the `If` condition for this.

Comment: Edited my answer, by the way.